# strtok function design

Tags: c, c99

strtok() function uses static variable.

Thus it's not re-entrant. and cannot be used to parse multiple strings.

What I want to know is why strtok() is designed this way?
strtok_r() should have been strtok().

Will this function going to stay in standard library in future?

Comment: Because it was written a long time ago, before multi-threading was common and it wasn't taken into account in the interface design

Comment: Even if multi-threading is not taken into account, it's still flawed, because you cannot parse more than one string at the same time.

Comment: This is too subjective a question to answer. I've voted to close it. The question of *why* it was designed this way can only be answered by the person who initially did and he's going to be hard to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function won't change.  Backward compatibility is a big thing for standards.

Why is the function not reentrant?  Well, I wasn't there in the 70s when it was designed, but I assume that reentrency wasn't needed for the use cases it was written.  Then its use spread of as it was useful and keeping compatibility was more a desirable than the added flexibility of reentrency. And finally the committee normalized the existing practice and instead of designing a new solution when there was already existing one.